# How do I fix this syntax error? Piston Position

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to write a python code to plot the piston position of a crank shaft rotating at constant angular velocity. Equation : x = rcos(theta) + sqrt(l^2 - (r^2)(sin^2(theta)))

So far I have written this out:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def piston_position (t, r1, l):
    return (r1 * np.cos(t) + ((l**2) - (r1**2) * (np.sin(t)**2)**0.5)

t = np.linespace(0,361,50)
y5 = piston_position(t,3,15)

plt.plot(t,y5)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting a syntax error on t = np.linespace(0,361,50), saying invalid syntax. I am unsure as to why this is incorrect as in a previous code the same method works out cleanly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def yFall (t,v0,y0):
   return (-9.8*t*t/2+v0*t+y0)

t = np.linspace(0,3,11)
y5 = yFall(t,5,30)

plt.plot(t,y5, 'b^--', mfc = 'r')
plt.title ("position")
plt.ylabel ("time")
plt.xlabel ("speed")
plt.show()
```

Would appreciate any help with this problem! Thank you.

Comment: one says `linspace` and the other `linespace`...

Comment: Whenever you get a mysterious syntax error ("But there is nothing wrong with that line!"), look up.  You probably have a missing closing parenthesis or bracket in a previous line.  In this case, look carefully at the return statement of the function `piston_position`.

Comment: It's pretty easy to count the number of opening brackets and closing brackets. Those two numbers need to match.

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The parser is getting confused because you left off a closing bracket `)` ~

```
def piston_position (t, r1, l):
    return (r1 * np.cos(t) + ((l**2) - (r1**2) * (np.sin(t)**2)**0.5))
```

This leads python into trying to understand the next code block as part of the numerical formula.  Thus it reports a syntax error.